# Passing Values via constructor

Tags: c#, parameter-passing

Passing a textbox's contents from form to another.

I have been told numerous times how to do it, I attempt it yet I fail at it.
I seem to pass the value fine but the `Mailer.cs` form somehow loses what it just receives.

Here's the code from my `ContactList.cs` which is supposed to send the `SelectedTo.Text` to the `Mailer.cs` `MailTo.Text` control.

This is just a piece of code, only need to display the problem areas.

```
public partial class ContactList : Form
{
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
    public Mailer mailerOwner;

    public ContactList(Mailer mailerOwner)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += ContactList_Load;
        this.mailerOwner = mailerOwner;
        ConfigureGrid();
    }
```

And here is the method for sending to Mailer.cs

```
private void OkAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Mailer mailer = new Mailer(SelectedTo.Text);
    this.Close();
}
```

Now here the init call from Mailer.cs

```
public Mailer(string contactlist)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MailTo.Text = contactlist;
}
```

What am i doing wrong? :|

Comment: Could you be more specific about *what* isn't working? Your code looks ok at first glance.

Comment: You have a Mailer object in your ContactList class, but you create a new instance in the Click handler with the text. Is that really what you want to do?

Comment: You are not update the form you think you are.  In your click event, you are creating a _new_ form and updating that and then throwing it away.  Is `mailerOwner` the form you wish to update?  In your `OKAdd_Click` method, just use `mailerOwner.MailTo.Text = SelectedTo.Text`.  This assumes that the MailTo textbox is public.

Comment: private void OkAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Mailer mailer = new Mailer(SelectedTo.Text);
            mailerOwner.MailTo.Text = SelectedTo.Text;
            this.Close();
        }

I have MailTo on the other form set public as a modifier, but still same issue.

Answer (score 1):

In your OkAdd_Click event, you are instantiating a new instance of Mailer.  This instance then goes out of scope when the click event completes.  My guess is that it works just fine for the microsecond that mailer is instantiated.

If you make mailer a class-level member instead of a local member (at the event scope) you will probably see your results.

Comment: You mean move the Mailer mailer = new Mailer outside of the OkAdd method?

Comment: The command, "Mailer mailer = new Mailer(SomeText);" is two parts..  The mailer definition, "Mailer mailer;" and the instantiation, "mailer = new Mailer(SomeText);"  You have combined them into one statement.  So long as you *define* mailer at a higher scope you should be okay.  You can feel free to *instantiate* mailer within the click event if that's where it makes the most sense.